# Python hangman, replacing letters?

Tags: python

How do I make my python hangman game replace the underscores in the variable `blanks` with the correct letter if it is guessed.

I have the correct if statement but I am not sure how to get the letters replaced.

This is what I tried:

```
def main()
    if choice in correctAnswer:
        print("\nCorrect!\n------...\n")

        index = 0
        while index < len(correctAnswer):
            index = correctAnswer.find(choice, index)
            if index == -1:
                break
            print(index)
            index += 1

        used.append(choice)

        places = []
        place=correctAnswer.index(choice)
        blanks[place]=choice
        blanks=''.join(blanks)
main()
```

That gives me typeError: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
blanks = list(makeBoard(correctAnswer))

print (correctAnswer)

def main():
    used = []
    print(blanks)
    choice = input("\nEnter a letter:")

    if len(choice) == 1 and special_match(choice) == True:

        if choice in correctAnswer:
            print("\nCorrect!\n--------------------------------------------------------------------\n")

            index = 0
            while index < len(correctAnswer):
                index = correctAnswer.find(choice, index)
                if index == -1:
                    break
                print(index)
                index += 1

            used.append(choice)

            [choice if letter == choice else blank for blank, letter in zip(blanks, correctAnswer)]

            main()
```

Comment: can you fix indentation i can't fully understand your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd be better off working with a list because strings are immutable

```
>>> blanks = list('_______')
>>> answer = 'hangman'
>>> guess = 'g'

>>> blanks[answer.index(guess)] = guess
>>> blanks
['_', '_', '_', 'g', '_', '_', '_']
```

So this keeps `blanks` mutable so you can replace elements at will. Then when you want to display this to the user as a string

```
>>> ''.join(blanks)
'___g___'
```

A list comprehension could handle repeated letters

```
>>> [guess if letter == guess else blank for blank, letter in zip(blanks, answer)]
['_', 'a', '_', '_', '_', 'a', '_']
```

**Edit**
Please see the following quick demo, note you should add handling of incorrect guesses

```
answer = 'hangman'
blanks = list('_'*len(answer))
for guess in set('hangman'):
    blanks = [guess if letter == guess else blank for blank, letter in zip(blanks, answer)]
    print(''.join(blanks))
```

Output

```
h______
h__g___
h__gm__
ha_gma_
hangman
```

Comment: Could you show how to do it with repeated letters so I can mark as best?Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How do I display that as a string then?

Comment: Ok got it working but as your output shows it shows all of it. What would I do so it works like it should and only reveals the letters given?

Comment: I've done that, now. But your code ends up giving all of the word? If the users inputs `a` it should only give `_ a _ _ _ a _`?? How is that done?

Comment: Silly me... Lol figured it out :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
if guess_input in current_word:
    cpos = 0
    for letter in current_word:
        if letter == guess_input:
            guess = guess[:cpos] + guess[cpos].replace("*",guess_input) + guess[cpos + 1:]
        cpos += 1
```

Guess is equal to "*" * `len(current_word)`

In your case, you would use "_".

This works with repeated letters.

Answer (score 0):

i recently tried this as a hobby project.

i used regex to do the job.

```
inputRegex = re.compile(r'^\w{1}$')  #regex for checking if only one alphabet has been input

thisGuess = self.myGuess.text().upper()
check = re.findall(thisGuess, self.qDisp)
# now if there is match will be non zero
quest = list(self.qDisp) # conv the blank word display into list for easy replace
#find the position of the guess in the string
for check in re.finditer(thisGuess, self.quest):
   i = check.start() #this gives the starting position of the match
   quest[i] = thisGuess  # 


self.qDisp = "".join(quest) #to join the list into string from list created above loop
```