# Hangman in Python - Replace multiple characters in single string based on index python

Tags: python

Trying to create a game called `hangman` in Python.
I've come a long way, but the 'core' functionality is failing me.

I've edited out all the parts which are irrelevant for this question.

Here it comes:

```
    picked = ['yaaayyy']
    length = len(picked)
    dashed = "-" * length

    guessed = picked.replace(picked, dashed)

    while tries != -1:
        input = raw_input("Try a letter: ")
        if input in picked:
            print "Correct letter!"
            found = [i for i, x in enumerate(picked) if x == input]
            for item in found:
                guessed = guessed[:item] + input + guessed[i+1:]
            print guessed
```

Upon calling this script, python creates a variable named `guessed` containing 7 dashes `-------`
It asks the user for a letter and if the letter is correct, it will replace the `-` with the correct letter. But not keeping the previous letters.

The word to be guessed is `yaaayyy`

Output of code:

```
Word is 7 characters:
-------
Try a letter: a
Correct letter!
-aaa
Try a letter: y
Correct letter!
yyyy
```

Goal:

```
Word is 7 characters:
-------
Try a letter: a
Correct letter!
-aaa---
Try a letter: y
Correct letter!
yaaayyy
```

Comment: I think `guessed[i+1:]` should be `guessed[item+1:]`.

Comment: it works... just god damn. Thanks!

Comment: _"Upon calling this script, python [...] asks the user for a letter"_. Strange, it doesn't do that on my machine. I just get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'` on line 5.

Comment: I don't see the need for the `replace` call anyway. It just replaces the entire string with the entire dashed string. Is it just to copy the dashed string?

Comment: Yeah, should just be `picked = 'yaaayyy'`, and just `guessed = '-' * len(picked)`.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937153/python-hangman-replacing-letters)

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to be slightly wrong:

```
found = [i for i, x in enumerate(picked) if x == input]
for item in found:
    guessed = guessed[:item] + input + guessed[i+1:]
```

That last line should probably be:

```
guessed = guessed[:item] + input + guessed[item+1:]
```

**EDIT**

This seems simpler to me:

```
for i, x in enumerate(picked):
    if x == input:
        guessed = guessed[:i] + input + guessed[i+1:]
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm not sure if this is clearer or not, but it's probably a little more efficient:

```
guessed = ''.join(x if picked[i] == input else c for i, c in enumerate(guessed))
```

Comment: The join line is very nice. Barring that, I would've done 'guessed[item] = input' instead of recreating the list every time.

Comment: `guessed` is a `str`, and Python `str`s are immutable. I agree that making a `list` instead would be better, but that seemed like a bit too large of a change to suggest.

Comment: Ah -- new I was missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using python3 you can solve it by simply doing:

```
user_input = input()
guessed = ''.join(letter if user_input == letter else guessed[i] for i, letter in enumerate(picked))
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the previously inputted letter, though.