# The output prints none and is not enclosed with ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, printing, return

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    for char in secretWord:

        if char not in lettersGuessed:
            print('_',end=' ')
        else:
            print(char,end=' ')

print(isWordGuessed('apple', ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']))
```

The output is `_pp_eNone`

I want my output to be `_pp_e` while still using the print function to call the function.

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python hangman, replacing letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937153/python-hangman-replacing-letters)

Comment: Sorry about all the confusion.I have literally joined this site 30 seconds ago.

Comment: Ok I fixed it for you.  When I run the code as it is now, I get `_ p p _ e`.  Were you expecting something different?

Comment: How did you do this. Also I wanted to know if you can get '_pp_e'  while using print(isWordGuessed('apple', ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply modify this to:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
     for char in secretWord:
         if char not in lettersGuessed:
             print("_", end="")
         else:
             print(char, end="")
     return ""

print(isWordGuessed('apple', ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']))
```

The `None` is the implicit return value after you have looped through your for loop.

Comment: Thank you.But is there any other way to go about this problem.

Comment: Yes, of course. You could just add a `return ""` after you loop. This would solve the problem that `None` gets returned after you have finished your for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function `isWordGuessed` doesnt have any `return` keyword, the statement

`isWordGuessed('apple', ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's'])` will return `None`.

Now that is called inside a `print` method, so `None` will be returned to `print` function and it will be printed.

The reason of it occurring at the end of the `secretWord` is due to usage of `end` parameter in your `print` statement inside the `isWordGuessed`

P.S.
In python, variable names should be lowercase letters separated by underscores. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159745/3442707)