# replace underscore with correct guess letter, Python hangman

Tags: python

I am creating a hangman game and cannot replace '_' with the correct letter guessed.

I have seen other answers but still cannot figure out a relevant solution. I can't understand: [Python hangman, replacing letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937153/python-hangman-replacing-letters)

```py
# some code

#vars
real_word = random_word()
secret_word = str(['_'] * len(real_word))
attempts = 999
letter = []
letters_guessed = []

# some code

# If correct guess  
if letter in real_word:
        # Here replace '_' with letter # IF CORRECT
```

**Expected Result**: If the correct letter is guessed, replace it with underscore in secret_word (one letter can take place of more than 1 underscore).

Comment: What do you mean by "*find no solution the one most relevant*"? The answer to that post that you linked explains very well why it is easier to work with a `secret_word` as a `list` instead of a string. Voting to close as "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: The other answer you linked gives you as good an answer as you are going to get for your question. I'd recommend taking the time to understand that answer instead.

Comment: @Georgy I got the answer I need explanation how that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to keep track of the current letters is with a list. Lists are mutable so values can be changed in the middle of them with ease. With the following code, it will swap out matching letters.

```python
real_word = "test"
secret_word = ["_"] * len(real_word)

guess = input("Guess letter: ")

# Loop through the letters in the real word
for i, letter in enumerate(real_word):
  # Check if the current looped letter is equal to the guess
  if letter != "_" and guess == letter:
    # Set the underscore at that position to the correct letter
    secret_word[i] = letter

# Output list as joined string
print("".join(secret_word))
```

With the guess `t`, the code will output `t__t`

Answer (score 2):

code

```
real_word = 'stackoverflow'
secret_word = '_' * len(real_word)
attempts = 999
letter = []
letters_guessed = []



# some code
to_try_letters = ['s', 'x', 'c', 'o', 'f', 'l', 'a']
# If correct guess  
for letter in to_try_letters:
  letters_guessed.append(letter)
  if letter in real_word:
    index = [i for i, l in enumerate(real_word) if l == letter]
    for i in index:
      secret_word = secret_word[:i] + letter + secret_word[i+1:]
  print(secret_word)
```

Output

```
s____________
s____________
s__c_________
s__c_o_____o_
s__c_o___f_o_
s__c_o___flo_
s_ac_o___flo_
```

Comment: Can you please explain how these works from your code:.                                                                                               index = [i for i, l in enumerate(real_word) if l == letter]
    for i in index:
      secret_word = secret_word[:i] + letter + secret_word[i+1:]

Comment: The index = ... get the index of a letter that it equal that your guess. The secret_word = ... it’s just how you can replace a letter of string by index

Answer (score 1):

First, try to execute :

```
print(str(['_'] * len(real_word)))
```

To understand why you should use [join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead.

Then, just iterate over your string/list or whatever you chose and replace needed characters :

```
real_word = "hello"
secret_word = '_' * len(real_word)

letter = "l"

if letter in real_word:
    secret_word = ''.join(c if real_word[i]!=letter else real_word[i] 
                          for i,c in enumerate(secret_word))

print(secret_word)
```

Prints

```
__ll_
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right you could do it like this. Using strings and lists in the way that you do makes it complicated, however.

```
# some code

#vars
real_word = "somewords"
secret_word = str(['_'] * len(real_word))
underscore_indices = [2 + 5*n for n in range(len(real_word))]
attempts = 999
letter = "s"
letters_guessed = []

# some code

# If correct guess
if letter in real_word:
    for char_index in range(len(real_word)):
        if letter == real_word[char_index]:
            secret_word = secret_word[:underscore_indices[char_index]] + letter + \
                          secret_word[underscore_indices[char_index] + 1:]

print(secret_word)  # ['s', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', 's']
```